# Javascript with some Razor is not working externally

Tags: javascript, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a javascript function

```
 function GotoFPLoginPage() {
            var url = '@(ViewBag.Title)';
            if (url.includes("Home")) {
                window.location.href = "/FPLogin/Index";
            }
        }
```

Implementation:

```
<html onclick="GotoFPLoginPage()">
```

The purpose of this is when the user click any part of the page it will redirect to another target page.

This example is working fine if i use the function itself inside my `_layout page` but when i tried to make it a javascript file and make a unique name `Custom_JSFile` then calling the `GotoFPLoginPage()`  it is not working.

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Custom_JSFile.js")
```

Any idea is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do you modify the JavaScript function at all when you move it into a separate JavaScript file?

This line will not work in a .js file as you do not have access to the ViewBag.

```
var URL = '@(ViewBag.Title)';
```

The reason this works in a .cshtml file is because you are using razor syntax to access a c# object. This will insert the value from the object into the JavaScript and the result is what will be evaluated.

Since razor syntax is not valid in a JavaScript file (you also have zero context of the ViewBag in a JavaScript file), this will not work and your URL value will literally equal "@(ViewBag.Title)".

You will have to put the value from `ViewBag.Title` somewhere that JavaScript is able to access it.

Comment: Jacob's comment as to why is spot on. The only thing I would add would be to rework your implementation so that you onclick passes the variable <html onclick="GotoFPLoginPage('@ViewBag.Title'> and your function receives it function GotoFPLoginPage(url) . This would make it compatible. Remember that the razor engine produces the output and passes it client side, razor syntax is not available client side and that is where your js lives.